# npm package: package.json handling

Tags: json, node.js, npm, package.json

I'm trying to create a reusable NPM module.  The tutorial I'm following says that I need a `package.json` file in the `dist` folder.  So at first I just copied the `package.json` file from the root of my project into the dist folder and all was good.

The problem is, when it comes to source control, you really don't want anything in the `dist` folder to be checked in, so what I did was create a `package.dist.json` file in the root of my project and then in the build step copy it to the `dist` folder and rename it.

This is not working.  Here is my build script:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "transpile": "ngc",
    "package": "rollup -c",
    "minify": "uglifyjs dist/bundles/test-service.umd.js --screw-ie8 --compress --mangle --comments --output dist/bundles/test-service.umd.min.js",
    "build": "copyfiles package.dist.json dist && rename dist/package.dist.json dist/package.json && npm run transpile && npm run package && npm run minify && npm pack dist/"
},
```

Here are my devDependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "rollup": "^0.47.4",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2",
    "uglify-js": "^3.0.27",
    "copyfiles": "^1.0.0",
    "rename-cli": "^4.0.0"
  },
```

This isn't working I get an error saying:

> The syntax of the command is incorrect.

I'm not even sure if this is the best approach.  Is there a better approach?  If not, why is my `build` task not working?

Here is the rollup.config.js:

```
import angularInline from 'rollup-plugin-angular-inline';

export default {
    entry: 'dist/hello-world.js',
    dest: 'dist/bundles/hello-world.umd.js',
    sourceMap: 'inline',
    format: 'umd',
    moduleName: 'hello-world-app',
    globals: {
        '@angular/core': 'ng.core',
        '@angular/router': 'ng.router'
    },
    plugins: [
        angularInline({
            include: './dist/src/**/*.component.js'
        })
    ],
    external: ['@angular/core', '@angular/router'],
    treeshake: true
}
```

Comment: One of your other scripts must be malformed. Can you please update your question with the all of your package.json `scripts` (minify, transpile, et al)

Comment: I have update my question with all the scripts.

Comment: Do you mind posting your rollup.config file too.

Comment: I added rollup.config.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you are using windows, as a [quick google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=The+syntax+of+the+command+is+incorrect) indicates that the error is a windows command line error. This information is extremely helpful if you are ever seeking advice on command line issues (for future reference).

Try the following:

- wrap the file name you are copying/moving in quotes

  ```
  copyfiles "package.dist.json" dist
  ```
- Use windows path separator `\` (not unix/linux separator `/`) when copying/moving

  ```
  rename dist\package.dist.json dist\package.json
  # also try with quotes
  rename "dist\package.dist.json" "dist\package.json"
  ```

However, whenever trying to build a distributable module where users may want to fork your code and run their own builds on different platforms, I recommend a more robust technique for building your code which will work cross-platform.

- **Option 1**: gulp, grunt, and/or friends
- **Option 2**: write your build code in NodeJS. This can be just a simple JS file that does all of the copying, renaming, etc using NodeJS and the built in `fs` module. Your build command would simply be `"build": "node my-build-script.js"`.